# Como refrescar la informacion de un fragment después de subir información a Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Android en Kotlin que se compone de un fragmento principal que hace de dashboard, donde se cargan todos los datos desde Firestore, observando al ViewModel. Para subir datos, utilizo un dialog Fragment y me gustaría que, al guardar los datos y que el dialogo desaparezca (dismiss()), al volver al fragmento principal se cargaran los nuevos datos, sin necesesidad de ir a otro fragment y volver. Ambas clases comparten el mismo ViewModel.

Aquí esta el código:
Navego a ese dialogo, el cual actualiza información en firestore y necesito que al hacer dismiss() y volver a este fragmento se actualice automáticamente.`

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            viewModel.getUserFromFirebase(view)
            viewModel.getEvaluationFromFirebase(view)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { user ->
                    if (user != null) {
                        setUpLayout(user)

                        binding.recalculateTdeeBtn.setOnClickListener {
                            findNavController().navigate(CorporalCompositionFragmentDirections.actionCorporalCompositionFragmentToRecalculateEnergyExpenditureFragment())
                        }}}}
```

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo de que es lo que estás creando para darte una solucion ? gracias

Comment: ya esta, gracias

Comment: no entiendo tu codigo, pero firebase siempre tiene listeners de success y fail o complete, en success o complete ejecuta el mismo codigo que ejecutas al abrir el fragment por primera osea el que carga los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar addSnapshotListener para escuchar los cambios en un documento, te devolverá dicho documento cuando se actualice algún dato, solo extraes la información de ahí y listo.

```
db.collection("Home").document("myDocument"). addSnapshotListener {doc ->
   /*TODO WITH DOC*/
   doc.toObject(MyClass::class.java)
}
```